# Changing commit message in GitHub pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have pushed some code for review and have been asked to change couple of my commit messages.

I tried doing `git rebase -i HEAD~5` since it isn't my latest commit which needs to be changed.

Upon making changes, I now see that my branch has been diverged.
What would have been the correct approach here?

I am not that confident, so would probably end up creating a new pull request all together. But, I would have liked to change in same pull request so that review comment history would have been retained.

Comment: What's wrong with what you did? Interactive rebase permits you to rewrite the commit messages for any of the commits within the purview of the rebase. You presumably did that. What's the problem?

Comment: I see that it rewrote but GitHUb statuscheck has a check to validate if Jira ticket was provided. It still fails as previous history shows commit messages without Jira ticket number

Comment: Well, there is no way to rewrite a commit message without making a new commit, and that is what you did. There is absolutely no way to rewrite the message of "the same" commit. So, yes, these are new commits and are not what was pushed previously. As you have already proposed, you could withdraw the pull request, construct a new version of the branch, and push it to make a new pull request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a new pull request.  You can simply make the changes to your commit messages (or any other changes you'd like to make to your commits) and force-push them to the same branch on the remote.  The pull request will be updated with the new commit contents.  You can do that either by specifying the `-f` option when you run `git push` or putting a plus sign (`+`) in front of the branch name when pushing.

Usually your CI system will realize that your commits have changed and run again on the new commits.  So if your old commits didn't meet the standard for whatever reason, that shouldn't be a factor in whether your new commits pass.

The benefit to updating the pull request is that it retains any description you've provided and any comments folks have provided on previous versions.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out if GItHub pull request has commit message changed?

Comment: One can look at the individual commits, but there isn't a notification in the interface when that happens, other than that a force-push occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.

- Through terminal, cd to repo directory
- Checkout to [FEATURE_BRANCH] that contains the commit message to be updated
- Run `git commit —amend`
- VIM editor will open, look for commit message and update, save and exit
- Run `git push —force-with-lease origin [FEATURE_BRANCH]`
- Commit message should be updated with new SHA hash.

**Note**

As per the git docs,

> In Git, the text of the commit message is part of the commit. Changing
> the commit message will change the commit ID--i.e., the SHA1 checksum
> that names the commit. Effectively, you are creating a new commit that
> replaces the old one.

**Reference**

https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-and-editing-commits/changing-a-commit-message